# Azure auth web page continuously open in the browser without stopping

Tags: r, shiny, azure-authentication

I used below code from https://github.com/Azure/AzureAuth/blob/master/vignettes/shiny.Rmd to do AzureAuth and redirect to my R Shiny app, but the Azure Auth page continuously opening in the browser without stopping, could anybody help?

Also, how to incorporate AzureAuth with my app credential? Thanks!

```
library(AzureAuth)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

tenant <- "your-tenant-here"
app <- "your-app-id-here"

resource <- c("https://management.azure.com/.default", "openid")
redirect <- "http://myurl.shinyapps.io/testing"

port <- httr::parse_url(redirect)$port
options(shiny.port=if(is.null(port)) 80 else as.numeric(port))

# replace this with your app's regular UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    verbatimTextOutput("token")
)

ui_func <- function(req)
{
    opts <- parseQueryString(req$QUERY_STRING)
    if(is.null(opts$code))
    {
        auth_uri <- build_authorization_uri(resource, tenant, app, redirect_uri=redirect, version=2)
        redir_js <- sprintf("location.replace(\"%s\");", auth_uri)
        tags$script(HTML(redir_js))
    }
    else ui
}

# code for cleaning url after authentication
clean_url_js <- sprintf(
    "
    $(document).ready(function(event) {
      const nextURL = '%s';
      const nextTitle = 'My new page title';
      const nextState = { additionalInformation: 'Updated the URL with JS' };
      // This will create a new entry in the browser's history, without reloading
      window.history.pushState(nextState, nextTitle, nextURL);
    });
    ", redirect
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
    shinyjs::runjs(clean_url_js)

    opts <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$url_search))
    if(is.null(opts$code))
        return()

    # this assumes your app has a 'public client/native' redirect:
    # if it is a 'web' redirect, include the client secret as the password argument
    token <- get_azure_token(resource, tenant, app, auth_type="authorization_code",
                             authorize_args=list(redirect_uri=redirect), version=2,
                             use_cache=FALSE, auth_code=opts$code)

    output$token <- renderPrint(token)
}

shinyApp(ui_func, server)
```